# public boolean removeStudent(int id)

Tags: java

Help me fix error please.

```
public boolean removeStudent(int id)
{
    for (Student student : this)
    {
        if ((student.getID()) == (id)) 
        return true;
        id.remove(); 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

Error: int cannot be dereferenced. 
I'm trying to remove a student from a list based on id. But the .remove is incompatible with ints.

Answer (score 1):

`id` is an `int`, a primitive type, so it doesn't have any methods.

```
id.remove(); //will never compile
```

Change your code to

```
for (int x =0; x < this.size();x++) {
    //your if should contain the removal and the return statements
    if ((this.get(x).getID()) == (id)) {
        this.remove(this.get(x)); 
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean to call `student.remove()` or something along those lines?

Also, that code won't be hit with the `return true` line before it.

Comment: Or perhaps `this.remove(student)`? Or something else? There isn't enough context.

Answer (score 0):

This code does not look very well. First off: The remove call is wrong and remove is always called as your if statement is not encapsulated with brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Reindent your code and you will see the problem:

```
public boolean removeStudent(int id)
{
    for (Student student : this)
    {
        if ((student.getID()) == (id)) {
            return true;
        }
        id.remove(); 
    }
    return false; 
}
```

See what you are currently doing: once you hit a student with matching ID, you will immediately jump out of the method, returning true.  Until then, you are removing all student you iterate.  i.e. You are removing all students, until you found a matching one.

It don't look quite normal to me.

I bet what you want to do is: remove all students with matching ID.  If any student is removed, return true, else return false.

If so, try to understand this piece of code:
(I am not giving you direct answer.  If you can understand what's going on in this piece of code then you can fix yours easily)

```
// print out only odd numbers in the list, and return true if there is any.
boolean printOdd(List<Integer> numbers) {
  boolean oddFound = false;
  for (int i : numbers) {
    if ((i % 2) != 0) {
        System.out.println("Odd Number Found: " + i);
        oddFound = true;
    }
  }
  return oddFound;
}
```

---

More problem in your code:

You don't seems using for-each look correctly.  Is your class a Collection?

```
 for (Type a : b) {...}
```

expect `b` to be a Collection (more precisely, Iterable) or an array.

Another problem is, id is an integer, what do you expect an `id.remove()` will do? You are telling an Integer to do "remove()"

I assume you are doing something like `this.studentList.remove(id)` or `this.studentList.remove(student)` ?